# New PList Retrieval Code Prevents MKMapView Delegate Method From Being Called (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, annotations, plist, android-mapview

I added a plist database to store information for annotations in a MKMapView. Once I implemented the code to grab the information, my delegate methods are no longer being called.

The code I added was:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MillersStores" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSArray *anns = [dict objectForKey:@"Root"];
    for(int i = 0; i < [anns count]; i++) {
        float realLatitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Latitude"] floatValue];
        float realLongitude = [[[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Longitude"] floatValue];

        MillersLocations *myAnnotation = [[MillersLocations alloc] init];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
        theCoordinate.latitude = realLatitude;
        theCoordinate.longitude = realLongitude;
        myAnnotation.coordinate = theCoordinate;
        myAnnotation.title = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Title"];
        myAnnotation.subtitle = [[anns objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"Address"];
        [mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        [annotations addObject:myAnnotation];
        [myAnnotation release];
    }
}
```

And this is one of delegate method that's no longer being called is:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *) mapView viewForAnnotation:(id ) annotation {
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
    pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout = YES;

    UIImageView *leftIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MillersAnnotation.png"]];
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftIconView;

    UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    return pinView;
}
```

I have another delegate method in there that also zooms into the User's Location that's not being called either, as well as the calloutAccessoryControlTapped method that's no longer being called.

I know it has something to do with the new code, but I'm confused as to how to even debug this because it's not giving me errors and I can't log it because the entire methods aren't even being called. When I get rid of the new code, the old code works fine...What is it in the new code that negates the old code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the map view's `delegate` property is not set.

Did the old code contain this line:

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

Add that to `viewDidLoad` or, in IB, connect the map view's `delegate` outlet to File's Owner.

Comment: Oh right, that's it. I had // commented out the old code and accidentally left the delegate declaration inside the comments.